How to split a wide HTML page into two pages when printing
I have a very simple HTML page with 42cm of width (doubled width of A4).
original HTML page
When I try to print it, I get croped version of this page, smth like this:
print
But instead of this, I want to have two printed pages, which I can use as an album.
1st should contain:
1st printed page
2nd should contain:
2nd printed page
So it was a very simple explanation of what I wanted to do. Actually, I want to do it with Puppeteer, or Unoconv, or even Gotenberg.
My current code is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <style>
        @media print {
            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }

        .template {
            width: 42cm;
        }

        .image {
            border: 1px solid;
            width: 100%;
            background: #c0c0c0;
            padding: 10cm;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 100pt;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Test print</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="template">
    <div class="image">
        wide block
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


Please share your Puppeteer code as a [mcve]. If you haven't written any, I suggest trying to write something, then asking when you're stuck on a particular technical problem. Thanks.

Be aware that you probably will need a borderless printer.

@ggorlen, thanks for your recommendation and fast reaction. But first of all, I want to try to make it with a very simple web page + chrome print/export dialogue. Just to be sure that it is even possible. Later I plan to create a much more complicated HTML page and use puppeteer or unoconv to convert it into PDF.

@ratmalwer yes, sure, I know it.

You could print it twice. once with margin-left:0 then with margin-left: -21cm

then you will have to skip image padding: 10cm or change it to the new needs
